# How can I authenticate user at laravel postRegister function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I would like to use larevel passport for admin user. At authentication controller, I have a problem that postRegister doesn't authenticated even though created user and saved it to database. What can be cause this problem? Can you give me an idea? I will very appreciated if you help me..

##### `admin/AuthController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\AdminUser;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getRegister()
    {
        if (view()->exists('auth.register')) {
            return view('auth.register');
        }
    }

    public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name'=>'required|string',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:admin_users,email',
            'password'=>'required'
        ]);

        $user = new AdminUser([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>md5($request->password)
        ]);
        $user = $user->save();

        $credidentials = ['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password];
        
        if (!Auth::attempt($credidentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Can not Login'
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access');
        
        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

##### `web.php`

```
Route::get('register', [\App\Http\Controllers\admin\AuthController::class, 'getRegister'])->name('register'); 
Route::post('admin.register', [\App\Http\Controllers\admin\AuthController::class, 'postRegister'])->name('admin.register');
```

##### `AdminUser` model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class AdminUser extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

config/auth.php

```html
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
         
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
        ],
        
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admin_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\AdminUser::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admin_users' => [
            'provider' => 'admin_users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Solution**

In your AuthController postRegister() handle function like this:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', //Better use regex
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = AdminUser::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password), //uses bcrypt
    ]);

    $credidentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (!Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credidentials)) { //use guard instead of normal Auth
        return abort(401); //Return error if failed authentication
    }

    $user =  Auth::guard('admin')->user(); //Access user through guard

    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access')->accessToken;

    return redirect('path');
}
```

You are doing everything else right but Auth::attempt() defaults to users model and you are using AdminUser model so you have to use `Auth::guard('custom_guard_name')->attempt($credentials)` and everything shall work.

Always use Auth::guard for custom authentications.

And also use `Hash::make($request->password)` for storing passwords as Auth also checks with bcrypt verify while logins.

Comment: Ps: dont mind the typos I’m on mobile rn.

Comment: Unfortunatelly,  it returns the same result. Auth::attempt($credidentials) gives false. I am trying to use laravel passport for both users and admin_users table. It authenticate when using Users model. But when using AdminUsers it only saving user to database and user doesn't login.

Comment: @RCeyda can you tell if you are using separate tables for admin and users? If yes then auth::attempt is looking for logins in users table by default and your admins are in admin-users to fix this you have to modify config/auth.php

Comment: I installed laravel ui vue --auth. But I' m getting the same result. after registered with user model, user automatically logins but not with adminUser model.

Comment: @RCeyda updated solution problem was in controller as Auth::attempt default checking with users table and failing you're being returned to 401 error, You have to specify guard using Auth::guard('guard_name')->attempt($creds) to login using custom guards/tables.

Comment: also note that you're returning user to login page even after login success so change return path accordingly I've left ``return redirect('path');`` path empty so change it later on.

Comment: @RCeyda do mark solved or solution if your problem is solved so that others with same issue can find solution. also if there is issue in solution lmk.

Comment: actually my problem didn' t solve. I wanted that after a user was be regusters, he/ she can be login automatically. I used laravel vue auth ui and passport. But no problem there isn' t any error.

Comment: @RCeyda for implementing passport with vue that part is supposed to be completed by developer as that’s not a issue but need implementation but for reference: https://adevait.com/laravel/api-authentication-with-laravel-passport by now you’ve already completed the token part and make the callback part as shown in tutorial.